# Error When Installing DotNetNuke (5.5) Module - Error reading the zip package

Tags: dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-module

I have created a custom module on my local machine and have installed it to a remote server successfully a number of times using standard DNN deployment methods.

Suddenly, when I try to install a new version, I receive the following error:

**Error reading the zip package - see below**

```
StartJob    Reading Installation Manifest file
StartJob    Creating Manifest
Info    Added File to manifest - 01.00.00.SqlDataProvider
Info    Added File to manifest - Uninstall.SqlDataProvider
Info    Added File to manifest - CustomNavNewsletter.dll
Info    Added File to manifest - ViewCustomNavNewsletter.ascx
Info    Added File to manifest - EditCustomNavNewsletter.ascx
Info    Added File to manifest - Settings.ascx
Info    Added File to manifest - ViewCustomNavNewsletter.ascx.resx
Info    Added File to manifest - EditCustomNavNewsletter.ascx.resx
Info    Added File to manifest - Settings.ascx.resx
EndJob  Created Manifest

Info    Reading Package Manifest - Module - Stratomer.CustomNavNewsletter
Info    Reading Component Manifest - Script
Info    Found valid path () for 01.00.00.SqlDataProvider.
Info    Found valid path () for Uninstall.SqlDataProvider.
Info    Reading Component Manifest - Module
Info    Module Manifest read successfully
Info    Reading Component Manifest - Assembly
```

**Failure   File specified in the dnn could not be found in the zip file: - C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\dnn\Install\Temp\ldqlkmal\CustomNavNewsletter.dll**

```
Info    Reading Component Manifest - File
Info    Found valid path () for ViewCustomNavNewsletter.ascx.
Info    Found valid path () for EditCustomNavNewsletter.ascx.
Info    Found valid path () for Settings.ascx.
Info    Found valid path (App_LocalResources) for ViewCustomNavNewsletter.ascx.resx.
Info    Found valid path (App_LocalResources) for EditCustomNavNewsletter.ascx.resx.
Info    Found valid path (App_LocalResources) for Settings.ascx.resx.
```

I've been desperately searching and cannot seem to resolve this.  Any assistance would be truly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this problem yesterday. Check your CustomNavNewsletter.dnn file. Inside there you will see all of the required files needed to make an installation successful. Anyways, if you go down to where it says CustomNavNewsletter.dll inside your CustomNavNewsletter.dnn file, look to see if there is a  folder  above that line. I will copy my code quick to give you an example.
`<file>
<path>bin</path>
<name>Arke.NewsFeed.dll</name>
</file>`

For where it says path, if you have it in another folder, replace bin with whatever name your folder is. When I make my installation zip's I like to move the required files into another folder and make my installation there, and just move my .dll into a bin folder.

Hope this helps!

Matt

Comment: This helped me as my module name had spaces in it, but the .dnn file <name> changed the spaces to underscores. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!

Answer (score 1):

Can I ask the obvious question: Is CustomNavNewsletter.dll in the root of your package?  Because that error message is indicating that the installer is looking there for it.

Are you using a DNN 4 manifest in DNN 5?  That combination means that the installer doesn't look in the right place for .dll files.  If you're using a DNN 5 manifest, are the .dll files in a `<component type="Assembly">` section (good), or in a files section?

Comment: No, it's in the bin folder inside the zip file